# Can we restrict specific users to access some databases in Athena and remaining users should see the other databases?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, data-lake

Problem statement:
Can we restrict specific users to access some databases in Athena and remaining users should see the other database?

- We have datalake created in s3 bucket. It is in development stage.
- Same s3 bucket datalake is used by end user at client side.
- These client users can see in development phase databases which creates confusion for them. Naming conventions does not help in this case.
- Can we restrict access to the user level in order to avoid unwanted databases to appear for client users?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is definitely possible from looking at the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/fine-grained-access-to-glue-resources.html).

You could create an IAM policy that you could attach to users who should not have access with a policy similar to the below

```
{
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": [
        "glue:GetDatabase"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:11111111111:database/example_db"
    ]
}
```